# C# validate input syntax and replace values

Tags: c#, string, validation

I am trying to make a function that validates an input string format and then replaces some values. The string should contain data in the following format:
    `string data = "'({today} - ({date1} + {date2}))', 'user', 'info'";`

I want to make sure that the string is typed in the above format format(validate it), and if it is to replace the values of `today`, `date1` and `date2` with some values.

I am thinking of something like that, but I don't know if that is the best way:
    `if (data.Contains("{today}") && data.Contains("{date1}") && data.Contains("{date2}"))`
`{` `}`

Anybody can suggest something?

Comment: I think, better way would be using a regular expresison, and check if string matches it.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry for the late answer, yes I agree with you, using a regex would be better. Could you give an example?

Comment: As I understand, the would be real dates in places of 'date1' and 'date2', right?

Comment: Actually, they are just integers, it should be something like today's date - (10 + 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you asked, if I understood your comment correctly.

```
string data = "'({today} - ({date1} + {date2}))', 'user', 'info'"; // your string

string pattern = @"\{.*?\}"; // pattern that will match everything in format {anything}
Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern); //create regex using pattern

MatchCollection matches; // create collection of matches
matches = regEx.Matches(data); // get all matches from your string using regex

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) // use this cycle to check if it s what you need
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[i].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate your string, what you have suggested is fine. You could make it easier by checking for the negative:

```
if(!myString.Contains("{today}")
    // handle error

if(!myString.Contains("{date1}")
    // handle error
```

In order to replace the values, you can use `String.Replace(...)`.

```
var myReplacedValue = myString.Replace("{today}", valueToRepalceWith);
```